# if clauses in terraform 0.12

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am new to Terraform, using Azure...I am trying to build a module "compute" where I can deploy a single vm or a vm set.

For a single VM I need a network interface, a security group association, and a azurerm_linux_virtual_machine. For a vm set I need to provision only azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set. **Is it possible to pass a boolean variable to this module to select which resources get executed?**

I've checked [this post](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9) but apparently there is no such thing.

Should I simply divide the module into compute/vm and compute/scale_set and actually have two modules, one for single vms and one for vm sets? Not sure if this will be a pain to maintain in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a boolean to select what is built. Generally speaking, you can use the `count` control:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {
    count = var.single_only ? 1 : 0
    ... (rest of config)
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set" "vm_set" {
    count = var.single_only ? 0 : 1
    ... (rest of config)
}
```

(see the end of [this section on `count` resources](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html#working-with-count-on-resources))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible and you don't need to divide the module.

As the statements in the posted [link](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9):
[image]

You can accomplish the resource creating selection by using the `count` parameter and `conditional expression`.

In this case, you can declare two bool variables like this:

```
variable "create_vm" {
  description = "If set to true, it will create vm"
   type   = bool
}

variable "create_vmss" {
  description = "If set to true, it will create vmss"
  type = bool
}
```

and define the resource `azurerm_linux_virtual_machine` and `azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set` in the same VM module.

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "example" {
  count   = var.create_vm ? 1 : 0
  name                = "example-machine"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                = "Standard_F2"
...

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set" "example" {
  count               = var.create_vmss ? 1 : 0
  name                = "example-vmss"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = "Standard_F2"
  instances           = 1
  admin_username      = "adminuser"

....
```

Then call the submodule like this,

```
module "vm" {
  source = "./modules/vm"
  create_vm = true
  create_vmss = false
  ...
}
```

Hope this helps.